# Array as new and non new

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to understand if the a diffrent between 2 types of writing arrays.

I tried to check here but did not find any similar question.

What are the differences between:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"ab","axc"};
```

AND

```
String[] arr2 ={"ab","axc"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference. `String[] arr2 = { "ab", "axc" }` is just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

According to the [Java Language Specification § 10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer may be specified in a field declaration (§8.3, §9.3) or local variable declaration (§14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10.1), to create an array and provide some initial values.

Omitting `new String[]` is only possible on field declaration or local variable declaration:

> Each variable initializer must be assignment-compatible (§5.2) with the array's component type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Examples:

```
// This works:
String[] array = { "abc", "def" };

// This does not:
String[] array2;
array2 = { "abc", "def" };
```